# How to display loading gif in vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm very new to vue. what I'm trying to do is have a loading gif while waiting for the endpoint to return.

I'm trying to use watchEffect, but I can't figure it out.  If it's the right way how do I do it?  If not what should I use instead?

Thanks

EDIT: Code

```
<template>
    <div class="player-list" :key="playerList.id" v-for="playerList in players.playerLists">
        <PlayerList :playerList="playerList" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import getPlayers from "@/composables/getPlayers";
import PlayerList from "@/components/PlayerList";
import { watchEffect } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'PlayerLists',
    components: {
        PlayerList
    },
    setup() {

        const { players, error, load } = getPlayers() //request endpoint
        load()

        watchEffect(() => {
            console.log('watch effect function')
        })

        return { players, error }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should show what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks!! I edited my question with the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vue apps should be data-driven. So, instead of relying on effects, change how your app looks by setting your data. If you're fetching some data from an endpoint, it's safe to assume you'll be putting it somewhere to display it in your app, like a `Ref`.

So, why not display your loading spinner *as long as your `Ref` is not the data it is waiting to become?* i.e., display a GIF while `someRef == null`?

```js
<template>
  <img v-if="data === null" src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
  <div v-else>
    <div>Here's the data!</div>
    <pre>{{ data.toString() }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const data = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      // Replace this `fetch` call with whatever your endpoint call may be.
      fetch('./endpoint')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => data.value = json);
    });

    return { data };
  }
};
</script>
```

Does that make sense? Your app should be modelling your data. You can take advantage of the fact that "a loading GIF should only be displayed while we do not have the data" to, well... display a GIF as long as the data is unset.

Comment: yeah it makes sense and works! thanks Matthew

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using the **latest syntax** with `<script setup>` and `computed()`

```
<template>
    <img v-if="loading" :src="your/path.gif" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const data = ref();
const loading = computed(() => data.value? true : false);

onMounted(() => {
  try{
    const resp = await fetch('your-api/url')
    data.value = resp;
  }
  catch (error){
    console.log(error);
  }
})
</script>
```

Similar to normal refs, you can access the computed result as `loading.value`. **Computed refs** are also **auto-unwrapped in templates** so **you can reference them without** `.value` in template expressions.

A computed property automatically tracks its reactive dependencies. Vue is aware that the computation of `loading` depends on `data`, so it will update any bindings that depend on `loading` when `data` changes.

---

In case you are having issues with the **gif** not been loaded from the start of the animation each time, check [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614496/how-to-show-a-gif-animation-from-the-start-every-time-condition-is-met-vuejs-3).